# Maven ANTLR generating wrong directory

Tags: antlr4

I have the following pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>db.project</groupId>
<artifactId>engine</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <antlr4.visitor>true</antlr4.visitor>
    <antlr4.listener>true</antlr4.listener>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
                <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>antlr4</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Normally, I use ANLTR 4 plugin which is described in this link : https://github.com/jknack/antlr4ide . But I want to use maven now, when I update my grammar in com.db.project directory, parser and lexer are generated in both default package (i.e., src/default package) and src/com/db/project/ twice, whereas I only want my lexer and parser in src/com/db/project/  directory. (including both .g4 file and java files in the same package)

How can I change this via pom.xml?

Comment: Have you tried version 4.2 of the antlr4-maven-plugin? I made significant improvements to the Maven integration in that version.

Comment: Hello @280Z28, I havent tried ANTLR 4.2. how can I use it? will it solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple change `4.0` to `4.2` in your `antlr4-maven-plugin`'s version tag.

Note that the plugin will recursively scan `src/main/antlr4` for `.g4` grammar files. If your grammar resides in `src/main/antlr4/com/company` then the package of your generated parser/lexer files will be `com.company`.

Here's a small template project to get you started, in case you need it:

https://github.com/bkiers/antlr4-template

Comment: Actually, I have a question now @bart-kiers, I did the same things but I still get lexer-parser files twice (one is in (default-package),other is in  src/db/propect). I also created target/generated-sources/anltr4/db/project directory, my grammar also generates its lexer and parser files in there. How can I ignore my grammar in order not to generate in both default package and src/db/project. I only want my lexer-parser in target/generated-sources/antlr4/db/project directory.

Comment: I found a way by disabling the ANTLR plug-in tool. I only deal with mvn install and generate-sources. that is, when I save my grammar, the grammar does not generate its lexer-parser, I have to run mvn generate-sources or mvn install. do u have better way?

Comment: No, I don't have another way: when changing the grammar, you'd have to do a `mvn generate-sources` or `mvn install`.

Comment: but your grammar (antlr4-template) works when I save the grammar. I just do not comprehend what my mistake is in my project itself:/